# How to set a title when export data using json format?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I don't know whether this is a proper title or not. I need to export some data into json format from mysql. I have a table which contains id, recommendData, level, room. My .php file has some codes:

```
<?php

$DB_HostName = "";
$DB_Name = "";
$DB_User = "";
$DB_Pass = "";
$DB_Table = "";


$con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 

$query = "SELECT max(id),recommendData,room,level  FROM $DB_Table";

$res = mysql_query($query,$con) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close($con);

$rows = array();
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $row[] = $r;
}

    echo json_encode($row);
?>
```

What I have done above is to get the data from the max id. This is the json output:

```
[ { "level" : "2",
    "max(id)" : "3",
    "recommendData" : "8",
    "room" : "4F"
} ]
```

As you can see, the data of max(id) with others data mix together. What I wash to do put max(id) as a title of these data, some thing like this:

```
{"max(id)" :[ { "level" : "2",
    "recommendData" : "8",
    "room" : "4F"
} ]}
```

Can anyone tell me how to do that??

Answer (score 1):

In your `while` loop you can setup the output array manually:

```
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
        $row[$r["max(id)"]] = array(
            "level" => $r["level"],
            "recommendData" => $r["recommendData"],
            "room" => $r["room"]
        );
}
```

Hope this helps!